# What does space character mean in a MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

Can not figure out how to read below query and usage of space character between them

```
SELECT `product`.`id` AS `product_id`, `order_date_meta`.`meta_value` AS `enrollment_date`
FROM `$wpdb->posts` `product`
INNER JOIN `$wpdb->term_relationships` `term_rel` ON `term_rel`.`object_id` = `product`.`ID`
INNER JOIN `$item_meta` `product_type_item_meta` ON `product_type_item_meta`.`meta_key` = '_product_id'
    AND `product_type_item_meta`.`meta_value` = `product`.`ID`
INNER JOIN `$items` `item` ON `item`.`order_item_id` = `product_type_item_meta`.`order_item_id`
INNER JOIN `$wpdb->posts` `order` ON `order`.`ID` = `item`.`order_id`
    AND `order`.`post_status` IN ('wc-completed', 'wc-processing', 'wc-partially-paid')
INNER JOIN `$wpdb->postmeta` `order_customer_meta` ON `order_customer_meta`.`post_id` = `order`.`ID`
INNER JOIN `$wpdb->postmeta` `order_date_meta` ON `order_date_meta`.`meta_key` = '_completed_date'
    AND `order_date_meta`.`post_id` = `order`.`ID`
WHERE `term_rel`.`term_taxonomy_id` = '$termId'
AND `product`.`post_status` = 'publish'
AND `product_type_item_meta`.`order_item_id` = `item`.`order_item_id`
AND `order_customer_meta`.`meta_key` = '_customer_user'
AND `order_customer_meta`.`meta_value` = '$userId'
ORDER BY `order_date_meta`.`meta_value` DESC
```

For example in line 4, what does space mean between `$wpdb->term_relationships` and `term_rel`?
Or space between `$wpdb->postmeta` and `order_customer_meta`?
Can't Google it because can find out how to tell Google what I mean about this space in query:)

Comment: Short answer: Its use as alias in `FROM` clauses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be asking about this:

```
FROM `$wpdb->posts` `product`
--------------------^
```

The important point here isn't the "space character".  It is the string following the table name.  This string is a *table alias*.  Table aliases are used to refer to tables in the `FROM` from clause.

In many cases, they are cosmetic -- although I highly recommend using them anyway.  I generally prefer very short table aliases that are abbreviations for the table name.  In this case, I would prefer `p`.  The aliases are then used to *qualify* column names, so it is clear what tables the columns are coming from.

In some cases, though, they are required -- namely when the same table is used multiple times in a `join` or correlated subquery.  In this cases, the aliases distinguishes the different references to the same tables.

If there is no explicit alias provided, then the table name itself is the default alias.

Answer (score 0):

Is a table name alias

```
INNER JOIN `$wpdb->term_relationships` `term_rel` ON `term_rel`.`object_id` = `product`.`ID`
```

is way for use another, normally shorter,  name for refer to object in SQL.

As you can see after the declaration:

```
 `$wpdb->term_relationships` `term_rel`
```

the reference to `$wpdb->term_relationships` is based on the alias:

```
 ON `term_rel`.`object_id`
```

The space just need for the syntax separating the object name and the corresponding alias.